# JavaScript Array Length Key Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is this extremely basic JavaScript array giving me a length of 13 when there are only 3 key/value pairs in it.  It makes sense that it might think 13 as 0 based index and my last array has a key of 12, but I need to have any array that has a key/value pair that returns me the correct number of pairs.  The keys need to be numbers.

http://jsfiddle.net/fmgc8/1/

EDIT: this is how I solved it thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/fmgc8/4/

Comment: you can't use strings to index an array.  javascript is converting your '12' to 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no diffrence between `array['12']` and `array[12]` (array['12'] is not considered as  *associative array* element). To find associative array [length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)

Answer (score 6):

it's because the highest number you have is:

```
array['12'] = 'twelve';
```

This creates an array length of 13 (since it's 0 based).  JavaScript will expand the array to allocate the number of spots it needs to satisfy your specified slots. `array[0..9]` is there, you just haven't placed anything in them.

Answer (score 1):

The `length` property of arrays returns the biggest non-negative numeric key of the object, plus one. That's just the way it's defined.

If you want to count the key-value pairs, you're going to have to count them yourself (either by keeping track of them as they are added and removed, or by iterating through them).

Answer (score 1):

Or, rearrange your array like this:

```
var array = [];

array.push(['10','ten']);    
array.push(['11','eleven']);    
array.push(['12','twelfe']);        

alert(array.length);
```